# My question is regarding the UX design , why do we always place a sidebar towards left being a right handed person I regret having it on my left hand

Tags: gmail

Example consider a google Gmail Desktop version, it is placed towards left and many more application like this ,and people says that due to western style our attention of eye moves from left to right was one of the reason behind the design, may be there could be few options for left and right handed people .But my question is why most of the designs have placed their sidebar towards left hand side only ?

Answer (score 6):

The sidebar typically is placed at the beginning of your **reading direction**. Reading direction doesn't have anything to do with left or right handedness. The point of placing navigation at the beginning of the page is to allow you to find and navigate to the right piece of information before you get lost in content.

This means that for right-to-left languages, the navigation also is on the right:

[image: Hebrew Wikipedia]

[image: Google Maps]